# How do you print the select statements for the following Slick queries?

Tags: scala, slick

I would like to find out which of the following queries would be the most efficient for getting a row count on a table, so I'm trying to print out the select statements. I know you can add`.selectStatement` to a Queryable but don't know if this tells me the complete truth because I'll have to remove the result generating code, e.g. `.list.length` and replace it with `.selectStatement`. Slick probably picks up that you are looking for the length and optimises further, so I want to see the select statement for the whole query, including the SQL that will be generated because of the `.list.length`, or `.count).first`

```
Query(MyTable).list.length

(for{mt <- MyTable} yield mt).list.length

(for{mt <- MyTable} yield mt.count).first
```

Comment: If you're on *nix "tail -f /path/to/query.log" should do the trick, no?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using H2 in the worksheet, but will play with it.

Comment: @virtualeyes, that seems to be the best (and only) solution. For the worksheets and H2 you need to change the trace level in the database url, e.g. implicit val session = Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4", driver = "org.h2.Driver").createSession(). Please give your suggestion (kindly mention worksheets) as answer.

Comment: your answer is the better one for H2, might come in handy for others, answer it yourself ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not been able to print the select statements using Slick, but Virtualeyes made a good suggestion: Look at the database logs!

Well, I test my Slick code in Scala Worksheets, and this is how you go about setting it up - For the worksheets and H2 you need to change the trace level in the database url, e.g.

```
implicit val session = Database.forURL(
"jdbc:h2:mem:test1;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4", 
driver = "org.h2.Driver")
.createSession()
```

This will tell H2 to log just about everything. Keep in mind though, that you will have to increase the 'maximum number or lines to output' in preferences -> Worksheet.

It also turns out that setting Slick at the right level of logging will serve the same purpose.

Thanks virtualeyes for alerting me to the elephant in the room :-)

Answer (score 16):

In play-2.2.1 with slick 2.0.0, in application.conf have:

```
logger.scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 9):

In Slick 3.1.0 (and I suppose in 3.0) you can make very cool sql debug:

```
[DEBUG] - slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement - Preparing statement: select "id", "email", "name", "password" from "users" where ("email" = 'petya@mail.ru') and ("password" = ext.crypt('123456',"password"))
[DEBUG] - slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.benchmark - Execution of prepared statement took 56ms
[DEBUG] - slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - /----------------------+---------------+-------+----------------------\
[DEBUG] - slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - | 1                    | 2             | 3     | 4                    |
[DEBUG] - slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - | id                   | email         | name  | password             |
[DEBUG] - slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - |----------------------+---------------+-------+----------------------|
[DEBUG] - slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - | 4fe6e5c3-af74-40f... | petya@mail.ru | petya | $2a$10$WyOrBy7p48... |
[DEBUG] - slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - \----------------------+---------------+-------+----------------------/
```

I use only logback configuration for logging, so it's very easy turn on:

```xml
<logger name="slick" level="INFO" />
<logger name="slick.jdbc" level="DEBUG" />
```

Answer (score 8):

In `Playframework 2.4.x` with `Slick 3.0+` use following entry:

`<logger name="slick.jdbc" level="DEBUG"/>`

Answer (score 5):

In Slick 3.0 you can now directly get the SQL for execution directly

```
val q = coffees.filter(_.supID === 15)
val action = q.delete
val affectedRowsCount: Future[Int] = db.run(action)
val sql = action.statements.head
```

See http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#querying

Comment: that seems to work only for `FixedSqlAction` though? Doesn't work with a generic `DBIO`, e.g. a join

Answer (score 4):

If you have a logging framework set up, you can set `scala.slick.session=DEBUG` to log connection pool events and queries.

(Note: Setting `scala.slick=DEBUG` will drown you with information from the query compiler)